# How long does it take the UK embassy to grant tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, embassies, copenhagen, application-status

I will be in Denmark soon and I was wanting to apply for a tourist visa to UK from Copenhagen.

What is the duration the embassy will need to give me a visa. Usually it says 2 weeks, is it reliable?

Answer (score 5):

In October 2014, the British consulate in Copenhagen decided 100% of all General Visitor  applications within 15 days.  They report an average of less than 10 days.  These figures would be strongly indicative of what you can expect in December 2014 and January 2015.

https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times

If you are only in Copenhagen for 16 days, it's possible, but cutting it close.  You may wish to see if you qualify to use one of their premium services.

http://www.ge2dk.tpcontact.co.uk/services-general

Comment: I just went through the link and it says I'm not capable of applying for the visa coz at first i was once rejected for the schengen visa

Comment: It means you cannot use the premium service. You can still apply without premium service.